# Why isn't the Node.js tcp socket being garbage collected?

Tags: node.js

```
var net = require('net');
var tcpServer = net.createServer(function(socket) {
    console.log('new client');
});
tcpServer.listen(8888);

var gccount = 0;
function gc() {
    console.log('force gc:', gccount);
    ++gccount;
    global.gc();
}
setInterval(gc, 1000);
```

Why can't the object `socket` be Garbage Collected after the callback returns?

Comment: what do "socket collected" mean ?

Comment: collected means garbage collected（GC）

Comment: Try calling `socket.end` and listen if it closes without it (`end` event).

Comment: I'm pretty sure you need to run node with `--expose-gc` for call to work.